# Membrr - {exp:membrr:order_form} not retaining values on error

Tags: membrr

I am using {exp:membrr:order_form} to submit billing information.

I tried entering some dummy data for credit card and sure enough, I get redirected to the same page and I get error messages.

My problem is that the input values I entered prior to submission like name, address, etc did not persist. They are all blank.

Is there a way to make them persist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you passing the related template variable into value attribute of input type. Like:

```
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="{first_name}" />
```

Comment: Ok, it works great for most of the fields. But the hidden field where I put the plan_id still doesn't carry over.